# iOS - Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: ios

I am facing some issues with google's OAuth2 client on ios using the library(OAuth2client-https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client‎).
I have registered my APP with the Google API's Console.
I trying to authenticate inside the UIWebView controller in a native iOS App.

My initial issue was, `UIWebView` showing blank view... just white screen.
This issue is fixed by editing the clientID details like, giving App store ID(instead of blank ID).
After this, I got the Google Login screen in my Native iOS App and next I tried to login.

After that onwards, I am getting an error screen in the UIWebView controller.
Following is the error:

> Error: invalid_client
>
> The OAuth client was not found.
>
> Request details
>
> cookie_policy_enforce=false
>
> ..........
>
> ..........

Please anyone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Alvin